# Installing light switch timer

Tags: switch, light

I am replacing switches in my 1950s house and want to put a new switch timer for my porch light. There was a old one already in place. I am confused because I installed the switch next to it using the black and red wire and the only wire left are 2 black ones?? The new timer has a red, blue and black wire. I am new to the home improvement world so am i missing something??

Comment: Model # of new timer so we can see the wiring diagram? Model # (or picture) of the old timer for comparison?

Comment: What do the instructions with the new timer say? You don't say anything about white wires in the switch box. If you have no white wires, then you probably don't have a neutral in the box. Do the instructions state that your new timer requires a neutral?

Comment: You're required to install every electrical gadget according to ***its*** labeling and instructions, NEC 110.3.   Meaning you need to read the instructions for the device: knowledge doesn't transfer between different models.  Also in US wiring, wire color codes are not standardized. The only hard rules are that ground is green or bare, and neutral is white or gray.  (But white or gray *in cable* can be hot!)

Comment: I must admit that i don’t remember how the old switch was wired. There is no white wire and the instructions do say it requires a neutral wire....

Comment: Can you post photos of the inside of the box please?